# Test page for jQuery plugin shows flash of unstyled code when viewed in Chrome - why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slidedown

I am trying to implement a basic slide down panel using jQuery, based on the following plugin:

http://samuelgarneau.com/lab/slidebox/

The problem I'm having is that there seems to be a flash of unstyled content (from the panel) in the top left corner when I look at it in Chrome. Here is the link:

http://www.asolidsite.com/clients/glennstar/custom/index.html

This doesn't happen in the plugin demo - so I must've mucked something up. But I've tried playing with all kinds of things, to no luck. Wondering if there might be someone with some jQuery insight.

I wonder if the jQuery bg resizer might be interfering with things (and causing it to lag so much on load...).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the source code around to have the fullscreen background javascript together and the slider javascript together? Because right now you have one, then the other and then the jquery action for each in turn. It might be better to have the fullscreen background script, then the jquery action, then the slider script followed by the jquery action. I'd also add the cufon script at the bottom because even if it doesn't load immediately, it has the least impact on functionality.

Also, if that doesn't work for you, change the fullscreen background and the slider scripts around, so the slider loads before the fullscreen background. As it is quite a large file, this could be causing the jitter.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullscreenr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
          <!--
          var FullscreenrOptions = {  width: 1400, height: 895, bgID: '#bgimg' };
          jQuery.fn.fullscreenr(FullscreenrOptions);
          //-->
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slidebox.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">  
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#slider").slideBox({width: "100%", height: "200px", position: "top"});
                });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
```

By the way (and off-topic), I think the design is beautiful. If I'm right, I used to live real close to this area, Medicine Hat, AB.

Comment: Wow - good eyes, Paul. Yeah - this site if for a company near Red Deer. I had no idea the positioning of the javascript code could cause hijinks! I've just learned something new - thank you! Tried the example way you suggested above without success. But you've given me a great starting point. I may have to look for a different way to build the sliding panel. I'll keep you posted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well - figured it out with the help of a friend. I needed to add a "display:none" to the div that was showing. Sometimes it's the simplest things... But Paul, you taught me to play with the positioning of my javascript - which was a wholly new idea to me. Thank you ever so much for your assistance!

Comment: Oh, my fave area ever is the Kananaskis, so I've driven by that area many times. Anyhow, the positioning of the JS can cause issues if it is a large file, or is calling something large. In your case, it's calling the bg.jpg, which is huge in web terms. Just the bg.jpg & intro-home.png alone are over 1 Mb, so it's very possible that your FOUC is coming from that, as the JS will essentially have to march on the spot until it is done loading before continuing to call the rest of the script(s).

Comment: ....Try and load the page with a very small image, just to see if it FOUCs. I can't promise that it's the issue, but it's where I would start faultfinding.

Comment: OK, oops! I had these sitting here ready to submit before you commented, as I was double-checking something using Yslow. So apologies for commenting after you've fixed it, good job on figuring it out. This is why I love web development, it's so accomplishing.